# angular 4 unable to route to changelog generated

Tags: angular

I'm unable to redirect to my changelog generated at the root of my project. I'm trying to redirect the user to this changelog when he types the URL of the application /changelog

exp: http://myProject/changelog

I have added new component changelog but when I navigate to the page I have a blank screen

changelog.routes.ts

```
export const changelogRoutes: Route[] = [
{
    path: 'CHANGELOG',
    component: ChangelogComponent
}
];
```

changelog.component.html

```
<p>
<link href="//file/../../../../CHANGELOG.md" type="text/css" />
</p>
```

changelog.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [ChangelogComponent],
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(changelogRoutes),
],
providers: [],
entryComponents: [ChangelogComponent]
})
```

the changelog.md is generated at the root of the project **project/changelog.md** and my app.routes is at **project/src/app/app.routes.ts**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by moving the chagelog to a folder inside app and passing the generated changelog on an embed tag html

```
<embed src="assets/changelog/changelog.md" width=100% height=100% />
```